# VMWare Fusion - Running Windows Natively From A Bootcamp Partition on OS X

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I have a copy of OS X Leopard running on a partitioned hard drive. The other partition has a copy of Windows XP running on bootcamp. As a result of this I can boot into either Windows xp OR Mac OS X natively.

I want to be able to run them both at the same time which i've been told can be doing using VMWARE Fusion..

My question is, how do i go about doing this once I have a copy of VMWare Fusion?

Answer (score 3):

From the [Getting started manual](http://www.vmware.com/pdf/fusion_getting_started_20.pdf):

> **To create a virtual machine from the Boot Camp partition**
>
> 1. From the Virtual Machine Library
>      window, select Boot Camp partition, 
>      which is automatically detected, and
>      click the run arrow.
> 2. Enter your Mac password to access the Boot Camp partition.  You must
>      have administrator privileges to use
>      the Boot Camp as a virtual  machine.
>      VMware Fusion creates a virtual
>      machine from your Boot Camp  partition
>      and starts Windows.
> 3. After Windows boots from your Boot Camp virtual machine,  VMwareFusion
>      starts the installation of VMware
>      Tools to enable full  virtual machine
>      functionality and optimize performance
>      for your Boot  Camp partition when
>      used as a virtual machine. Follow the
>      onscreen  instructions and restart
>      your virtual machine when prompted.
> 4. When the VMware Tools installation is complete, reboot your computer. 
>      The first time you power on your Boot
>      Camp virtual machine after installing 
>      VMware Tools, you will need to
>      reactivate Windows.

Works fine, though sometimes a second copy of the bootcamp item appears in the selector menu, this is harmless. Virtualised XP is great!

Note [Parallels also allows integration with Bootcamp](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/bootcamp/), and it may be [possible though seems not well supported in Virtualbox](http://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=8&t=19866)...

Comment: This feature is one of the main selling points of VMWare fusion over VirtualBox for me.  Does anyone know if Parallels can do this as well?

Comment: Yes, I actually find Parallels handles the Bootcamp partition better than VMWare when it works (both faster, less delay on first boot), but Parallels is more buggy than VMWare, so it is a trade-off; I run Parallels on my machine but set up VMware for my co-workers - all using a VM bootcamp XP.

Comment: I have to say that VMware 3 (which I own) and Parallels 5 (which I’ve been trying for the next 12 remaining days), are on par with the number of bugs. I’d say VMware 3 actually has *more* issues than Parallels 5. That’s my experience after using vmware3 since launch and suddenly downloading parallels trial and importing my vms. I see more issues with vmware. I use Visual Studio 2008, Vista, XP and SQL 2008 primarly. Also Ubuntu 9.10 works “out of the box” with Parallels (even compiz and such). Under VMware I had sound/video issues and tools were a PITA. VMware 2 vs Parallels 4< was different.