# Clean install of Windows 7 from Boot Camp to VMware Fusion

Tags: windows-7, mac, virtual-machine, boot-camp, vmware-fusion

Hey guys I'm currently trying to ditch Boot Camp in favour of VMware Fusion. I've seen this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/30371/vmware-fusion-running-windows-natively-from-a-bootcamp-partition-on-os-x/30376#30376) here but what I want to do is to get rid of my Boot Camp partition and do a clean install of Windows 7. So my questions are:

1. How do I do that?
2. Is there a legal issue? Note that I won't be using the one in Boot Camp anymore.
3. Any activation problems? Do I have to deactivate the old one first? If yes how do I go about that?

Additional info:

1. I'm using an late 2009 early 2010 27" iMac
2. It's a Windows 7 Professional acquired from MSDNAA

Comment: So do you want to migrate (title) or do a clean installation (first paragraph)?

Comment: Sorry my title's a little misleading. I meant a clean install. :)

Comment: So, you basically want to know how to install a fresh Windows in VMware. That's covered in the main screen when you start VMware without bootcamp, second item on the right. Or is there more to your question?

Comment: That's only the first part. My main concern would be with question 2 and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answers to your questions:

1. Choose *File* -> *New…* in VMware and follow the instructions.
2. No legal issue since it's still one installation.
3. You may need to reactivate since the hardware that Windows sees would be different. There is a [good article at the VMware knowledge base](http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=1015925) about this.